# interactive liquid metal ball with Three.js

Tags: javascript, syntax, three.js, vertex

I am making my first steps with JavaScript and playing with Three.js too.

Today I am watching the tutorial of Paul Lewis to make an interactive liquid metal ball with Three.js like this one http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/reactive-ball/

I was asking me if it's possible to make it with an external model using the ThreeBinaryLoader. I change the code to this http://codepen.io/gnazoa/pen/wKVLNG but it doesn't work because I have a syntax error here

```
sphereGeometry = loader.load( 
    "sources/obj/mmlogo/mm_logo.js", 
    function(
      200,      // radius
      60,       // resolution x
      30);      // resolution y
```

So I tryed with another syntax:

```
var loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
            loader.load( "sources/obj/mmlogo/mm_logo.js", function ( sphereGeometry ) {

                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    color: 0x515151,
                    morphTargets: true,
                    overdraw: 0.5,
                    envMap: reflectionCube,
                    combine: THREE.AddOperation,
                    reflectivity: 1,
                    shininess: 0,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                } );
```

And I am still with same syntax problem.

I know that maybe is something really simple but for me have been very hard because I am learning and this something really complex.

Do you know if it's possible to make it with a correct syntax?

Comment: Try removing the `,` after `side : THREE.DoubleSide`.

Comment: Thank you. I already removed it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var loader = new THREE.BinaryLoader();
loader.load( "sources/obj/mmlogo/mm_logo.js", function ( sphereGeometry ) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
        color: 0x515151,
        morphTargets: true,
        overdraw: 0.5,
        envMap: reflectionCube,
        combine: THREE.AddOperation,
        reflectivity: 1,
        shininess: 0,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    } );
});
```

You have forgotten to close Your function with `});`. I wloud suggest using some IDE with syntax checking. Run time errors in Javascript will give You enough fun. ;)

Comment: I You tell us **how** it does not work, we may be able to help You better. Give us error You are getting.

Comment: The JavaScript console tells that there is an error in the syntax in my createObjects() function. Thank you for your help @Dark Anagver

Comment: Well, You had syntax error in the code You provided. I do not see createObjects function in Your code, so I am unable to help You.

Comment: I put the complete code here http://codepen.io/gnazoa/pen/wKVLNG just tell me what do you need. Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, I will not analyze Your entire project for You, this is not what SO is for. If You have specific problem, and if You are able to state it - please do so. Otherwise, it would be just me debugging Your code. :)